# JSFiddle does not work locally

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jsfiddle

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to get my JSFiddle to display and work properly locally.
[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kelseyhisek/8vku6pta/)

When I save the page source from JSFiddle, the spacing of columns seems off and the JQuery does not work at all.

If anyone could help me out I would HUGELY appreciate it! Thanks so much!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo by kelseyhisek</title>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <style type='text/css'>
    @import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,400italic,700italic,700");
 .delete {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-left:10px;
    height:50px;
    margin-right:10px;
    width:1%;
}
.delete:hover {
    -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
    width:20%;
}
.days {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    width:166px;
    margin-top:30px;
    font-family:"Roboto";
    font-weight:400;
    font-size: 15px;
}
ul {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
.colcontent {
    width:1000px;
    top:100px;
    height:800px;
    position:absolute;
}
.connectable_list1 {
    /* background:blue;*/
    width:166px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
.connectable_list2 {
    /*background:red;*/
    width:800px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
.todo {
    clear:both;
}
.asgn {
    font-family:"Roboto";
    font-weight:300;
    font-size: 13px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:146px;
    height:60px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-top:10px;
    background-color:#E8E8E8;
}
.td {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:146px;
    height:60px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    padding-left:30px;
    background-color:#E8E8E8;
}
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('a').hide();
$(".delete").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('a').show();
});

$(".delete").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('a').hide();
});

$(".connectable_list1").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable'
});
$(".connectable_list2").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
});

$('.delete').click(function () {
    $(this).parent("li").slideUp(200);
});

('.delete').mouseOver(

function () {
    $('a').show();
});
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="headings">
    <ul>
        <li class="days">MONDAY</li>
        <li class="days">TUESDAY</li>
        <li class="days">Wednesday</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="colcontent">
    <ul class="connectable_list1 connectedSortable">
        <li class="asgn"> <span class='delete' style="background-color:blue;"><a href='#'>x</a></span>
Assignment1</li>
        <li class="asgn"><span class='delete' style="background-color:red;"><a href='#'>x</a></span>Assignment2</li>
        <li class="asgn"><span class='delete' style="background-color:green;"><a href='#'>x</a></span>Assignment3</li>
        <li class="asgn"><span class='delete' style="background-color:green;"><a href='#'>x</a></span>Assignment4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="connectable_list1 connectedSortable">
        <li class="asgn"><span class='delete'><a href='#'>x</a></span>Assignment1</li>
        <li class="asgn"><span class='delete'><a href='#'>x</a></span>Assignment2</li>
        <li class="asgn"><span class='delete'><a href='#'>x</a></span>Assignment3</li>
        <li class="asgn"><span class='delete'><a href='#'>x</a></span>Assignment4</li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <div class="todo">
            <ul class="connectable_list2 connectedSortable">
                <li class="td"><span class='delete'>x</span>Todo1</li>
                <li class="td"><span class='delete'>x</span>Todo2</li>
                <li class="td"><span class='delete'>x</span>Todo3</li>
                <li class="td"><span class='delete'>x</span>Todo4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the *Console* output in your browser (e.g. <kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome/IE, FireBug in FireFox).

Off the top of my head try replacing `//ajax.googleapis.com` with `http://ajax.googleapis.com`; or download the file and reference that file with a relative path.

When you're running locally your protocol is `file://` and `//host` means "access `host` via the same protocol the page is using".

Also `href="/css/...` is absolute path so it'll look for the css file on your file system root (`/` in unix, `C:\` or `D:\` in Windows) that can cause a styling issue.

## Update

I'll try to walk through simply (as simple as handing network/file resources and 4 languages/libs at the same time can be ;)

I copied your code from the question into `D:\test\fiddle.html` and opened it in Chrome, then pressed <kbd>F12</kbd>. Get better acquainted with [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), web development without it is like cutting a 100 year old tree with a spreading knife. The basic usage is essentially: *Right click > Inspect element*.

> GET file:///D:/test/jquery.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND fiddle.html:6

The above line was modified by you after saving the page. It's because you included JQuery in the fiddle. Under **Frameworks & Extensions** set it to "No Library (Pure JS)" since you're including JQuery yourself with `<script>`. _That's the point of jsfiddle, that you don't have to write those tedious `<script>` tags.

> GET file:///D:/css/normalize.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND fiddle.html:7

Under **Fiddle Options** untick the **Normalize CSS** so this file won't be included. That file changes paddings and margins for a lot of elements, so to fix your layout add

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
```

> GET file:///D:/css/result-light.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND fiddle.html:8

This file is empty, safe to ignore.

> GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND fiddle.html:126
>   GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND fiddle.html:125

As you see here it's trying to load `file://...` which is non-existent. So change your include lines to

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined fiddle.html:92

Result of JQuery not included because of the schema being wrong (`//`).

You'll also need to move the two JQuery `<script>` tags before your `$(window).load(` script.

So here's your final file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo by kelseyhisek</title>
  <style type='text/css'>
    @import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,100,400italic,700italic,700");
 .delete {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-left:10px;
    height:50px;
    margin-right:10px;
    width:1%;
}
.delete:hover {
    -webkit-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: width .2s ease-in-out;
    width:20%;
}
.days {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    width:166px;
    margin-top:30px;
    font-family:"Roboto";
    font-weight:400;
    font-size: 15px;
}
ul {
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
.colcontent {
    width:1000px;
    top:100px;
    height:800px;
    position:absolute;
}
.connectable_list1 {
    /* background:blue;*/
    width:166px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
.connectable_list2 {
    /*background:red;*/
    width:800px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
.todo {
    clear:both;
}
.asgn {
    font-family:"Roboto";
    font-weight:300;
    font-size: 13px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:146px;
    height:60px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    margin-right:20px;
    padding-left:30px;
    padding-top:10px;
    background-color:#E8E8E8;
}
.td {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:146px;
    height:60px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding-top:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    padding-left:30px;
    background-color:#E8E8E8;
}
  </style>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('a').hide();
$(".delete").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('a').show();
});

$(".delete").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('a').hide();
});

$(".connectable_list1").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable'
});
$(".connectable_list2").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
});

$('.delete').click(function () {
    $(this).parent("li").slideUp(200);
});

('.delete').mouseOver(

function () {
    $('a').show();
});
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="headings">
    <ul>
        <li class="days">MONDAY</li>
        <li class="days">TUESDAY</li>
        <li class="days">Wednesday</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="colcontent">
    <ul class="connectable_list1 connectedSortable">
        <li class="asgn"> <span class='delete' style="background-color:blue;"><a href='#'>x</a></span>
Assignment1</li>
        <li class="asgn"><span class='delete' style="background-color:red;"><a href='#'>x</a></span>Assignment2</li>
        <li class="asgn"><span class='delete' style="background-color:green;"><a href='#'>x</a></span>Assignment3</li>
        <li class="asgn"><span class='delete' style="background-color:green;"><a href='#'>x</a></span>Assignment4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="connectable_list1 connectedSortable">
        <li class="asgn"><span class='delete'><a href='#'>x</a></span>Assignment1</li>
        <li class="asgn"><span class='delete'><a href='#'>x</a></span>Assignment2</li>
        <li class="asgn"><span class='delete'><a href='#'>x</a></span>Assignment3</li>
        <li class="asgn"><span class='delete'><a href='#'>x</a></span>Assignment4</li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <div class="todo">
            <ul class="connectable_list2 connectedSortable">
                <li class="td"><span class='delete'>x</span>Todo1</li>
                <li class="td"><span class='delete'>x</span>Todo2</li>
                <li class="td"><span class='delete'>x</span>Todo3</li>
                <li class="td"><span class='delete'>x</span>Todo4</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: I'm actually a student learning the basics of HTML, CSS and JQuery as part of my studio class (why I'm trying to save locally). Since I only really know the bare bones at this point, I'm not quite sure how to edit my existing code based on your feedback! I really appreciate your help though.

Comment: Thank you SO much!! I've spent hours trying everything I could think of to solve the issue so you've really been a huge help to me. (I also appreciate you walking me through each step--will be very valuable for later projects)